# How can i run NodeJS (NestJS) bachand Httpserver as background process on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, nestjs, background-process, httpserver

I need to run a Httpserver on local computers, which doesn't have proper internet connection. I am planing to install application to PCs and servers. By this way, users can launch my application from browser.

I know how to add .exe application to background processes from powershell. But I am not sure how to hanlde it with nodejs (maybe "node app.js" from command promt) and run script in installation process.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not sure if you checked converting your node app into exe, if not you can make one using NPM library like nexe, https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem with these converters are the file size of executable, more the 30 mb. The target computers has very limited internet connection and i must update them with max 2-3 mb data size. Initial data size is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i created a bat file and converted it to exe with this tool. It works like a charm.
https://www.chip.de/downloads/Bat-To-Exe-Converter_59802845.html